# Private notes on questions?

Tags: feature-request

How difficult would it be to add a private note feature to question pages? It would be interesting if one wants to make notes for work products on a page or implementation specifics without exposing those to the public.

Comment: I would put a note to vote you up as soon as I reach 15pts in here :)

Comment: In the meantime, there is a feature called [saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info), it was announced here: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019). 
For each saved post you can add a note up to 500 characters. Currently both saves and the notes are private - see [this related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391888).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bohahkiiknkelflnjjlipnaeapefmjbh#) has an extension that allows you to make private notes on web pages. [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickfox-notes/) also has a note-taking extension.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along this line. I think a specific Stack Exchange addin could be written though that would add more features than basic notes. Let's say, links to other questions, etc.

Answer (score 11):

My **unofficial** guess, based on what I've seen in the past, is that the team will reply thus:

> This would add a significant level of complexity to the system on our end and provide little meaningful benefit. We recommend that you just keep a local file of notes.

I would agree with such a stance.

Comment: I'd agree.  If your notes don't benefit everyone, then they don't belong on the server.

Comment: Yes, I would reply as such. Much like the requests to add better bookmarking of posts, there are applications that are *specifically* designed to annotate web pages. I can't see any benefit to the large development effort to store, track, and manage private annotations.

Comment: Ok, you say it's difficult to implement this and I believe you without effort, but I didn't find a single place in the whole system where to write something private, I don't want to install a plugin just for that. This request could be accepted at least partially. I would really appreciate...

Comment: I know asking a feature from user point of view, is like never going to have it. But again if its not accepted, is it not possible to allow a printing list? Where we can add them as chain and print ourself by pressing once?

Answer (score 6):

A completely off the wall suggestion:

Rather than use Firefox / Chrome / whatever to keep your notes organised, because let's face it, browsers are rubbish for this sort of thing (I always feel scrapbook is ok but not great for seriously lengthy notes, why not install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and then add [this script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77298) which adds a handy link to [Stackprinter.com](http://www.stackprinter.com/). You can then produce a dead tree copy, if you so like, or do what I do and use CUPS-PDF as the printer to archive questions I like. If you so wanted to, you could add pages to that pdf using one of the variety of scripts out there for your notes.

Of course, there is always the problem of the "moving target" that questions/knowledge become obsolete/superceded/updated very quickly, but such is the nature of anything.